Remix and Vite: Proxy Server cannot read assets url when set to subpath
So I have 2 web applications built with Remix:

www.example.com/knowledge-management-system, this web has basepath of /knowledge-management-system and has 3 sub paths:
a. /knowledge-management-system/technology
b. /knowledge-management-system/infrastructure
c. /knowledge-management-system/library

www.example.com/portal, this web has basepath of /portal and will be the main website. I need to set /knowledge-management-system as part of this web's application, let's say I have a KMS button which will link to web number 1, but as a proxy.


The condition is that I need to provide 2 different ways to access web number 1:

direct access to www.example.com/knowledge-management-system
access from inside web number 2

Both of steps above will never share login session from KMS web, so if I login directly from the KMS web, that doesn't log me in when I access it from proxy inside web 2 (Portal).
I have tried several configs, in which each of them has their own "problem".
Config 1
"/knowledge-management-system": {
   changeOrigin: true,
   secure: false,
   target: "https://example.com/knowledge-management-system",
   rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/knowledge-management-system/gi, ""),
},

This approach is valid, but there is 1 concern:
The url conflicts, we don't know whether www.example.com/knowledge-management-system is really from web number 1, or from proxy set from web number 2 as they share base root url from www.example.com
Config 2
"/apps/knowledge-management-system": {
   changeOrigin: true,
   secure: false,
   target: "https://example.com/knowledge-management-system",
   rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/apps\/knowledge-management-system/gi, ""),
},

This approach is somehow succeeded but also fails at the same time:
Accessing www.example.com/apps/knowledge-management-system, shows the web 1 (KMS), but failed to fetch its assets, it refers to /knowledge-management-system/assets  but the valid assets url is /apps/knowledge-management-system.
Is it possible to set proxy path deply, like sub path:

If I set the proxy from www.example.com/portal, then it will be www.example.com/portal/apps/kms -> proxy to www.example.com/knowledge-management-system, along with its asset path.
If I set the proxy from www.example.com, then it will be www.example.com/apps/kms -> proxy to www.example.com/knowledge-management-system

